# Does Flex provides some core components to display interactive maps, show lattitude/longitude, zoom and pan etc

Tags: apache-flex, maps, gis

I am new to GIS (geographical information system) domain. I just want to know if Flex provides some core components to display interactive maps, show lattitude/longitude, zoom and pan etc.

I know some third party APIs like, ARCGIS, ModestMaps, MapQuest etc but I want to know if Flex itself provides any support for this.

If it doesn't then which opensource API is the best to use.

Comment: Nothing built-in and the choice of API depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on Tour de Flex app to explore Flex capabilities and resources

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html